# Are there any gaussian contributions to ballistics?

Tags: biographical-details

Entry 93 in Gauss's famous mathematical diary states - "solution of a problem in ballistics". What is the problem in ballistics that Gauss solved? can someone give a reliable source to what Gauss actually solved?

Comment: If you read German, I can look in his complete works and search for you.

Comment: I don't read german, so i need someone to explain to me what he did.

Comment: In his commentary on Gauss's diary Gray skips entry 93, which suggests that no details are known. https://books.google.com/books?id=4mwSrfxBSzkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false